# MQQueueManager Constructor throwing FileNotFoundException

Tags: vb.net, exception, ibm-mq

I have the following vb.net code:

```
Imports IBM.WMQ
[...]
MQEnvironment.Hostname = hostName
MQEnvironment.Port = portNumber
MQEnvironment.Channel = channelName
queueManager = New MQQueueManager(queueManagerName) ' error here
```

which is throwing the following error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException occurred
FileName=C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\[...]\bin\Debug\mqclient.ini
HResult=-2147024894
Message=Could not find file 'C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\[...]\bin\Debug\mqclient.ini'.
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
```

I am not using any ini files in the construction of my queue manager, so does anyone have any idea what's going on - why is it even looking for one, and why in the same directory as the program? I have installed the MQ client, and afaik I have all the environmental variables, etc. set up properly.

Thanks for any help you can give

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that an unhandled or a first chance exception? Internally, the MQ .net layer will try to read a MQClient.ini but should function quite happily without it. It reads the file for compatibility with the C client, and can handle some of the MQClient.ini stanzas. I would not have expected an absence of such a file to cause problems, but it will try to open it internally. Was that the full callstack, as I'd have expected some MQ libraries on the stack otherwise.

Comment: I tried installing the MQ server (trial edition). That didn't work (another issue), but now that's been done this error''s gone away...

Comment: That was everything in Visual Studio's "copy error" option.